# retrieve data from firestore if textField has specific text swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm new to development and im using Firestore in my application, my goal is to get data from Firestore when the user writes `"Hello World"` in the textField. I managed to get data from the Firestore and everything is fine but when I use the `if` statement the function not launch the code.

this is my code without using `if` statement and it works 100%

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class orderTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

 @IBOutlet var order: UITableView!

 @IBOutlet var userNameField: UITextField!


var db: Firestore!
let DocRefernce:DocumentReference! = nil
var street = [String]()
var firstName = [String]()
var lastName = [String]()
var blockNumber = [String]()
var phone = [String]()
var houseNumber = [String]()
var block = [String]()
var Area = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    
    
    order.register(UINib(nibName: "Order1TableViewCell", bundle: nil) , forCellReuseIdentifier: "order")
    
    
    
    order.separatorStyle = .none
    order.dataSource = self
    order.delegate = self
    
    db = Firestore.firestore()
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
    
    loadData1()
    loadData2()
}


   func loadData1() {
    
    
    db.collection("Hi").getDocuments()
    {
        (querySnapshot, err) in
        
        if let err = err
        {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
        }
        else
        {
           
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
           
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())");
                
                self.firstName.append(document.get("firstname") as? String ?? "")
                self.lastName.append(document.get("lastname") as? String ?? "")
                self.street.append(document.get("street") as? String ?? "")
                self.blockNumber.append(document.get("blockNumber") as? String ?? "")
                self.Area.append(document.get("area") as? String ?? "")
                self.phone.append(document.get("phone") as? String ?? "")
                self.houseNumber.append(document.get("houseNumber") as? String ?? "")

                
            }
            
            
        }
        self.order.reloadData()
    }
    
    
}




func loadData2() {
    
    
    db.collection("hola").getDocuments()
    {
        (querySnapshot, err) in
        
        if let err = err
        {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
        }
        else
        {
         
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())");
                
                self.firstName.append(document.get("firstname") as? String ?? "")
                self.lastName.append(document.get("lastname") as? String ?? "")
                self.street.append(document.get("street") as? String ?? "")
                self.blockNumber.append(document.get("blockNumber") as? String ?? "")
                self.Area.append(document.get("area") as? String ?? "")
                self.phone.append(document.get("phone") as? String ?? "")
                self.houseNumber.append(document.get("houseNumber") as? String ?? "")
                
            }
        }
        self.order.reloadData()
    }
   }

 }
```

and this is the code where I use `if` statement but I couldn't manage to get data from the Firestore.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class orderTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {




@IBOutlet var order: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var userNameField: UITextField!



var db: Firestore!
//  let DocRefernce:DocumentReference! = nil
var street = [String]()
var firstName = [String]()
var lastName = [String]()
var blockNumber = [String]()
var phone = [String]()
var houseNumber = [String]()
var block = [String]()
var Area = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    
 
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    userNameField.delegate = self
    
    
    order.register(UINib(nibName: "Order1TableViewCell", bundle: nil) , forCellReuseIdentifier: "order")
    
    
    
    order.separatorStyle = .none
    order.dataSource = self
    order.delegate = self
    
    db = Firestore.firestore()
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
 if userNameField.text == "Hello World" {
     loadData1()
    } else {
        loadData2()
        
    }
    
  }




  func loadData1() {
    
    
    db.collection("Hi").getDocuments()
    {
        (querySnapshot, err) in
        
        if let err = err
        {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
        }
        else
        {
         
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())");
                
                self.firstName.append(document.get("firstname") as? String ?? "")
                self.lastName.append(document.get("lastname") as? String ?? "")
                self.street.append(document.get("street") as? String ?? "")
                self.blockNumber.append(document.get("blockNumber") as? String ?? "")
                self.Area.append(document.get("area") as? String ?? "")
                self.phone.append(document.get("phone") as? String ?? "")
                self.houseNumber.append(document.get("houseNumber") as? String ?? "")

                
            }
            
            
        }
        self.order.reloadData()
    }
}




func loadData2() {
    
    
    db.collection("hola").getDocuments()
    {
        (querySnapshot, err) in
        
        if let err = err
        {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
        }
        else
        {
           
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())");
                
                self.firstName.append(document.get("firstname") as? String ?? "")
                self.lastName.append(document.get("lastname") as? String ?? "")
                self.street.append(document.get("street") as? String ?? "")
                self.blockNumber.append(document.get("blockNumber") as? String ?? "")
                self.Area.append(document.get("area") as? String ?? "")
                self.phone.append(document.get("phone") as? String ?? "")
                self.houseNumber.append(document.get("houseNumber") as? String ?? "")
               
                
            }
      }
        self.order.reloadData()
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: The if statement is located in viewDidLoad method meaning that the code inside it will only be executed when the app starts up thus your textField won't have any text inside of it. You have to perform this checking procedure in textField's delegate, once the user puts some text inside of it and taps the return button / exits it in any other way. If that's what you're looking for, I can provide full explanation below - just respond to this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution that has already been briefly explained in the comment.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // The rest of your code besides that if statement should go in here...
    userNameField.delegate = self
}


extension orderTableViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // This is where your if statement goes
        if textField.text == "Hello World" {
            loadData1()
        } else {
            loadData2()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work for me , is there another way to retrieve data from firestore for specific user ?

Comment: The retrieval part is entirely architected by you. You stated that your code worked in the first example, but in the second one it didn't. I could help you write code that retrieves said data, but that goes beyond this question. Is there a bug in my code that prohibits it from executing? You said I didn't work for you but did you get any output, or did it merely not work. @mohammedbasheer

Comment: I think the solution that you give it to me it is the same for the second example , i tried all of them but no one works for me :(

Comment: I'd suggest you try debugging code inside `textFieldShouldReturn()`. Does it execute, and if not, where is the issue? It would be beneficial to create a repo on GitHub with this project if it's not confidential. That would allow me and others to quickly determine a bug and submit a pull request once we figured out the solution. I'd also love to provide a full explanation with that PR, as I know that fixing code for the sake of it working is not a good learning experience for you. Please consider that approach @mohammedbasheer.